# Show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(p)=\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

I have an expression for $p$ as follows:

$$P=\frac{e^{r\frac{T}{n}}-e^{r\frac{T}{n}-0.5\sigma^2\frac{T}{n}-\sigma\sqrt{\frac{T}{n}}}}{e^{r\frac{T}{n}-0.5\sigma^2\frac{T}{n}+\sigma\sqrt{\frac{T}{n}}}-e^{r\frac{T}{n}-0.5\sigma^2\frac{T}{n}-\sigma\sqrt{\frac{T}{n}}}}$$

When I plot it as a function of $n$, with $n$ varying between 1 to 260, it very clearly converges to 0.5 (the other parameters are set to $r=0.1$, $\sigma=0.2$, $T=1$):
[image]

However, I am unable to show this mathematically. Here is my attempt; first, $p$ simplifies to (getting rid of the dependence on $r$):

$$p=\frac{1-e^{-0.5\sigma^2\frac{T}{n}-\sigma\sqrt{\frac{T}{n}}}}{e^{-0.5\sigma^2\frac{T}{n}+\sigma\sqrt{\frac{T}{n}}}-e^{-0.5\sigma^2\frac{T}{n}-\sigma\sqrt{\frac{T}{n}}}}$$

Then:

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(e^{-0.5\sigma^2\frac{T}{n}-\sigma\sqrt{\frac{T}{n}}})=1$$

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(e^{-0.5\sigma^2\frac{T}{n}+\sigma\sqrt{\frac{T}{n}}})=1$$

So I get:

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(p)=\frac{1-1}{1-1}$$

Which is undefined.

Could anyone pls give me a hint at what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you ever heard of L'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: This expression simplifies a lot.

Comment: @Jan Stuller: you can factor $e^{-0.5\sigma^2\frac{T}{n}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, we start with

$$P(n) := \frac{e^r{\frac{T}{n}}-e^{r\frac{T}{n}-0.5\sigma^2\frac{T}{n}-\sigma\sqrt{\frac{T}{n}}}}{e^{r\frac{T}{n}-0.5\sigma^2\frac{T}{n}+\sigma\sqrt{\frac{T}{n}}}-e^{r\frac{T}{n}-0.5\sigma^2\frac{T}{n}-\sigma\sqrt{\frac{T}{n}}}}$$

To make life ***significantly*** easier, I will define some auxiliary constants

$$A := rT \qquad B := 0.5 \sigma^2 T \qquad C := \sigma \sqrt T \qquad D := A-B$$

and so

$$P(n) = \frac{e^{A/n}-e^{D/n-C/\sqrt{n}}}{e^{D/n+C/\sqrt{n}}-e^{D/n-C/\sqrt{n}}}$$

Multiply on top and bottom by $e^{-D/n + C/\sqrt n}$:

$$P(n) = \frac{e^{B/n + C/\sqrt n}-1}{e^{2C/\sqrt{n}}-1}$$

Since a $0/0$ indeterminant form arises, we may apply L'Hopital's rule: with some trivial algebra (negate minus signs, simplify the ratio of exponentials, and multiply top and bottom by $n^{3/2}$),

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} P(n) =\lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{e^{B/n + C/\sqrt n} \left( -\frac{B}{n^2} - \frac{C}{2n^{3/2}} \right)}{e^{2C/\sqrt{n}} \left(- \frac{C}{n^{3/2}} \right)}=\lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac 1 Ce^{B/n - C/\sqrt n} \left( \frac{B}{\sqrt n} + \frac{C}{2} \right) $$

It should be easy to conclude the desired result from here.

Answer (score 3):

I let you adapt the following computation to your case. What has to be computed is
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1-e^{- \alpha x-\beta \sqrt x}}{e^{-\alpha  x+\beta \sqrt x}-e^{-\alpha x-\beta \sqrt x}},$$
with $\alpha ,\beta >0$.

You have that $$e^{x}=1+x+o(x).$$ Therefore
$$1-e^{-\alpha x-\beta \sqrt x}=\alpha x+\beta \sqrt x+o(x),
$$
and
$$
e^{-\alpha x+\beta \sqrt x}-e^{-\alpha x-\beta \sqrt x}=2\beta \sqrt x+o(x).
$$

At then end
$$\frac{1-e^{- \alpha x-\beta \sqrt x}}{e^{-\alpha  x+\beta \sqrt x}-e^{-\alpha x-\beta \sqrt x}}=\frac{\alpha x+\beta \sqrt x+o(x)}{2\beta \sqrt x+o(x)}=\frac{\beta +\alpha \sqrt x+o(\sqrt x)}{2\beta +o(\sqrt x)}\underset{x\to 0^+}{\longrightarrow } \frac{\beta }{2\beta }=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Set $x=\sigma \sqrt{\frac Tn}$ and consider $x\to 0$. It follows
$$p = \frac{1-e^{-\frac 12 x^2 - x}}{e^{-\frac 12 x^2 + x} -e^{-\frac 12 x^2 - x}} = \frac{e^{\frac 12 x^2  +x}-1}{e^{2x}-1}\stackrel{L'Hosp.}{\sim}\frac{(x+1)e^{\frac 12 x^2  +x}}{2e^{2x}}\stackrel{x\to 0}{\longrightarrow}\frac 12$$

Answer (score 2):

Series expansion at $n \to \infty$:

$$P(n) \simeq \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{24} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{3/2} \sigma ^3 T^{3/2}+\frac{1}{360} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{5/2} \sigma ^5 T^{5/2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{7/2}\right)\underset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} \frac{1}{2}$$